# Getting Error on Assigning Variable Inside a Function

Tags: php

Can you please take a look at this script and let me know why I am getting the

> Undefined variable: step1

error?

```
<?php

$step1;

function getNums($num1, $num2){
 $diff = $num2 - $num1;
  $steps =[
        round($num1 + $diff/4), 
        round($num1 + $diff/2), 
        round($num1 + $diff*.75), 
        $num2
    ];
 $step1 = $steps[1];
}

getNums(50, 400);
echo $step1;

?>
```

Comment: The line `$step1;` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Look at the manual on variable scope, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code inside your function is in a different [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) than the code running outside of it, which is why you are getting an error about `$step1` being undefined - it is being defined outside the function. If you want to be able to refer to it inside your function you will either need to pass it in as an argument to your function by reference or make the variable `global`.

**Pass by reference**

```
function getNums( $num1, $num2, &$step1 ){
    // ... your code
}
// pass the variable by reference
getNums( 50, 400, $step1 );
echo $step1;
```

**Using `global`**

```
// accessible globally
global $step1;

function getNums( $num1, $num2 ){
    global $step1;
    // ... your code, with $step1 accessible
}

getNums( 50, 400 );
echo $step1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you pass it by reference?

```
<?php

$step1;

function getNums($num1, $num2, &$step1){
 $diff = $num2 - $num1;
  $steps =[
        round($num1 + $diff/4), 
        round($num1 + $diff/2), 
        round($num1 + $diff*.75), 
        $num2
    ];
 $step1 = $steps[1];
}

getNums(50, 400,$step1);
echo $step1;

?>
```

This should work